# How to set a ringtone on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ringtones

I have recently bought an iPhone. I don't know how to set a ringtone on an iPhone. Can anyone explain the procedure to set a ringtone in an easy manner?

Answer (score 2):

Open Settings → Sounds → Ringtone. Choose a ringtone from the list. As you choose a ringtone, it begins to play so you can preview it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to set or change a ringtone on your iPhone, then you can go to Settings → Sounds → Ringtone. Choose a ringtone from the list. 
If you mean to set a custom ringtone for your iPhone, then you can try to use iTunes or some iTunes alternatives like AnyTrans to make it with ease.